# PHP Extend array search function

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am currently using this method to find arrays by keys + values:

```
public static function getCountryDataByVal($array, $key, $value, &$results = array()) {
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return;
    }

    if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
        $results[] = $array;
    }

    foreach ($array as $subarray) {
        self::getCountryDataByVal($subarray, $key, $value, $results);
    }

    return $results;
}
```

This works fine so far, but there's a problem and i have no idea how to solve it. Let's assume, that i have this array structure:

```
array(8) {
    ["alpha2"]=>
        string(2) "ad"
    ["alpha3"]=>
        string(3) "and"
    ["numeric3"]=>
        string(3) "020"
    ["callingCodes"]=>
        array(1) {
            [0]=>
                string(3) "376"
        }
    ["tlds"]=>
        array(1) {
            [0]=>
                string(2) "ad"
        }
    ["currencies"]=>
        array(1) {
            [0]=>
                string(3) "eur"
        }
    ["longitude"]=>
        string(4) "42.5"
    ["latitude"]=>
        string(3) "1.5"
}
```

I can use the method above to find this array by `alpha2 = ad` for example. But what i need is the possibility to search for `eur IN currencies` for example.

Using this does not work:

```
getCountryDataByVal($array, 'currencies', 'eur');
```

because `eur` is not the value of the key `currencies`, but it's the value of a subkey.

Any idea, how i have to extend the method above to achieve this?

Comment: getCountryDataByVal($array['currencies'], 'eur'); ? :p

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#91365 seems like a nice recursive array_search function

Comment: getCountryDataByVal($array['currencies'], 'eur'); wont work and the function you've linked doesn't fit my needs.

Comment: array_search('eur',$array['currencies'])  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that function:

```
 public static function getCountryDataByVal($array, $key, $value, &$results = array()) {
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return;
    }

    if ((isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value )|| 
       (isset($array[$key]) &&  is_array($array[$key]) && array_search($value, $array[$key]) !== FALSE ) ) 
    {
        $results[] = $array;
    }

    foreach ($array as $subarray) {
        self::getCountryDataByVal($subarray, $key, $value, $results);
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Undefined index: currencies

Comment: could you try again, forget to add brackets for grouping in if-statement

Comment: Tried that already (`if (isset($array[$key]) && ($array[$key] == $value || (is_array($array[$key]) && array_search($value, $array[$key]))))`). However, i just get an empty result.

Comment: ok one more edit in the if-statement because array_search returns index (may be 0, so interpreted as false) or FALSE